# Unable to use Django Authentication System in Deployment

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django app which uses Django's builtin authentification system which works normally till I deploy it in a production environment.

I now got this error whenever I try to login or register a user:

`ProgrammingError at /login
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...`

All other aspects of my web app work correctly and so I'm unsure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run `python migrate [appName]` in production to create the necessary tables.

Comment: Do I run this in my normal terminal window

Comment: Yes, you can check django docs for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: When I do this it just says `No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Make sure you pushed all the migrations from your local env and also run `python manage.py makemigrations` before running `migrate`

Comment: I have tried this but it makes no difference to the deployed app

Answer (score 0):

use both
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate,
and checkout in database django_session should be there, if not delete migrations file in migrations folder and do above 2 steps again.